# How do I make a generator from two lists in python?

Tags: python, generator

Give lists a, b

```
a = [5, 8, 9]
b = [6, 1, 0]
```

I want to create a generator gen such that:

```
for x in gen:
  print x
```

outputs

```
5, 8, 9, 6, 1, 0
```

Comment: So ... you *don't* want `'9'` to appear in the output?

Comment: woops, my bad, edited to have the 9 in there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [5, 8, 9]
>>> b = [6, 1, 0]
>>> it=chain(a,b)
>>> for x in it:
    print x,
...     
5 8 9 6 1 0
```

Comment: `iter( .. )` does not make a generator, it makes a iterator. You would rather do `chain(a,b)`. `a+b` simply makes a new copy of both lists together, that's not efficient when you don't need that copy.

Answer (score 3):

```
def chain(*args):
    for arg in args:
        for item in arg:
            yield item

a = [5, 8, 9]
b = [6, 1, 0]
for x in chain(a,b):
    print x,

print ', '.join(map(str,chain(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)** for a ridiculously pythonic and elegant one-liner:

```
>>> a=[5,8,9]
>>> b=[6,1,0]
>>> g=(i for i in a+b)
```

test:

```
>>> for i in g:
       print i

5
8
9
6
1
0
```

or test #2, if you really prefer to have a comma between each item, :

```
>>> print ', '.join(map(str,g))

5, 8, 9, 6, 1, 0
```

Comment: `(i for i in a+b)` produces a new list c=a+b of length len(a)+len(b).  This may be less than optimal.

Comment: That's true, but optimizing wasn't a part of the OP's question ... and this is not really important for merging two lists on a modern computer, anyway. This is probably why python includes such sugars. Also, if you really want an optimal solution, I would suggest to move from python to C, somehow. But that's true, it's not optimal.